# get array value from Loop statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops

my php code is this

```
$newArr = array();

$newArr['Item1']=$array1;
$newArr['Item2']=$array2;
$newArr['Item3']=$array3;
$newArr['Item4']=$array4;
$newArr['Item5']=$array5;
$newArr['Item6']=$array6;
$newArr['Item8']=$array8;

echo json_encode($newArr);
```

i wanted to build a line chart with `chartjs` with those data. so the chart would looks like this....

[image]

here is my current code js......

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url : "http://localhost/clicklog/clicklog.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(newArr){
        //console.log(newArr.Item1);


        Clicks1 = [];
        Clicks2 = [];
        Clicks3 = [];
        Clicks4 = [];
        Clicks5 = [];
        Clicks6 = [];
        Clicks8 = [];

        for(var i in newArr){

            //console.log(newArr[i]);

            for(var x in newArr[i]){
                //console.log(newArr[i][x]);
                Clicks1.push(newArr[i][x]);

            }

        }

        console.log(Clicks1);
```

with this code, my variable "Clicks1" has this value

```
[18948, 13783, 9484, 5468, 46267, 33511, 22824, 13204, 5378, 3773, 2564, 1586, 18076, 13252, 8979, 5394, 10273, 7139, 4713, 2632, 8812, 6326, 4465, 2751, 18083, 12924, 8886, 5354]
```

which is comes from "newArray" without sorting.

i wanted to put value in the "var clicks1" only for those data that comes from "item 1"

here is the result of my php code..

```
{"Item1":{"2009-04-17":18948,"2009-04-18":13783,"2009-04-19":9484,"2009-04-20":5468},
"Item2":{"2009-04-17":46267,"2009-04-18":33511,"2009-04-19":22824,"2009-04-20":13204},
"Item3":{"2009-04-17":5378,"2009-04-18":3773,"2009-04-19":2564,"2009-04-20":1586},
"Item4":{"2009-04-17":18076,"2009-04-18":13252,"2009-04-19":8979,"2009-04-20":5394},
"Item5":{"2009-04-17":10273,"2009-04-18":7139,"2009-04-19":4713,"2009-04-20":2632},
"Item6":{"2009-04-17":8812,"2009-04-18":6326,"2009-04-19":4465,"2009-04-20":2751},
"Item8":{"2009-04-17":18083,"2009-04-18":12924,"2009-04-19":8886,"2009-04-20":5354}}
```

thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i wanted to put value in the "var clicks1" only for those data that comes from "item 1"

Here's how you do that, but keep reading:

```js
var newArr = {"Item1":{"2009-04-17":18948,"2009-04-18":13783,"2009-04-19":9484,"2009-04-20":5468},
"Item2":{"2009-04-17":46267,"2009-04-18":33511,"2009-04-19":22824,"2009-04-20":13204},
"Item3":{"2009-04-17":5378,"2009-04-18":3773,"2009-04-19":2564,"2009-04-20":1586},
"Item4":{"2009-04-17":18076,"2009-04-18":13252,"2009-04-19":8979,"2009-04-20":5394},
"Item5":{"2009-04-17":10273,"2009-04-18":7139,"2009-04-19":4713,"2009-04-20":2632},
"Item6":{"2009-04-17":8812,"2009-04-18":6326,"2009-04-19":4465,"2009-04-20":2751},
"Item8":{"2009-04-17":18083,"2009-04-18":12924,"2009-04-19":8886,"2009-04-20":5354}};

var Clicks1 = [];
var data1 = newArr.Item1;
for (x in data1) {
   Clicks1.push(data1[x]);
}
console.log(Clicks1);
```

...but then you'll have to keep doing that for `Clicks2` through `Clicks7`. Whenever you find yourself, in any programming language, with variables like "var1, var2, var3, var4" and so on, it tells you you want to use an *array* instead.

Without more context one can't say specifically how to change it, because we don't know what you're going to do with `Clicks1` through `Clicks7`, but you'll most likely want to change the PHP to be dealing with arrays (the non-associative kind), and then using the resulting arrays in your JavaScript code.

But for what it's worth, this gives you a single array with the data from each `ItemX` in your existing response, in order by `ItemX` label, in an array called `allclicks`:

```js
var newArr = {"Item1":{"2009-04-17":18948,"2009-04-18":13783,"2009-04-19":9484,"2009-04-20":5468},
"Item2":{"2009-04-17":46267,"2009-04-18":33511,"2009-04-19":22824,"2009-04-20":13204},
"Item3":{"2009-04-17":5378,"2009-04-18":3773,"2009-04-19":2564,"2009-04-20":1586},
"Item4":{"2009-04-17":18076,"2009-04-18":13252,"2009-04-19":8979,"2009-04-20":5394},
"Item5":{"2009-04-17":10273,"2009-04-18":7139,"2009-04-19":4713,"2009-04-20":2632},
"Item6":{"2009-04-17":8812,"2009-04-18":6326,"2009-04-19":4465,"2009-04-20":2751},
"Item8":{"2009-04-17":18083,"2009-04-18":12924,"2009-04-19":8886,"2009-04-20":5354}};

// An array we'll put arrays inside
var allclicks = [];
// Loop through the items in alphabetical order
Object.keys(newArr).sort().forEach(function(itemKey) {
  // Get the item for this key
  var item = newArr[itemKey];
  
  // Add an array to allclicks for this item's clicks
  itemclicks = allclicks[allclicks.length] = [];
  
  // Loop through this items dates to get the clicks
  for (date in item) {
    itemclicks.push(item[date]);
  }
});
console.log(allclicks);
```

Then you use `allclicks[0]`, `allclicks[1]`, etc., rather than `Clicks1`, `Clicks2`, etc.

Comment: your solution is work (y), you are great. sorry, i am quite new with "coding" or also can be said programming.

Comment: @MuhammadFebrik: Glad that's working! No need to apologize, we're all new at things all the time. :-)